# Applying JWT in DjangoRest

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am attempting to use SimpleJwt with a custom user model in my django app.
I have set up the user model, and created a user in it, And i also set-up the SimpleJWT in the settings.
My jwt in the settings is:

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": True,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": True,
    "UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN": False,

    "ALGORITHM": "HS256",
    "SIGNING_KEY": SECRET_KEY,
    "VERIFYING_KEY": "",
    "AUDIENCE": None,
    "ISSUER": None,
    "JSON_ENCODER": None,
    "JWK_URL": None,
    "LEEWAY": 0,

    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer",),
    "AUTH_HEADER_NAME": "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION",
    "USER_ID_FIELD": "email",  # Change this to "username"
    "USER_ID_CLAIM": "user_id",
    "USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE": "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule",

    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken",),
    "TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM": "token_type",
    "TOKEN_USER_CLASS": "rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser",

    "JTI_CLAIM": "jti",

    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM": "refresh_exp",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),

    "TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainPairSerializer",
    "TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSerializer",
    "TOKEN_VERIFY_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenVerifySerializer",
    "TOKEN_BLACKLIST_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenBlacklistSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainSlidingSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSlidingSerializer",
}
```

and my model is:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # Add your custom fields here
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    # Use field names as strings in REQUIRED_FIELDS
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'phone_number']
    
    # Add any additional custom methods or properties here if needed

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

I tried to login using a valid user I created that exists in the db and is activated, yet when i attempt to login using the "email" and "password" fields  I receive the following response:

```
{ "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials" }
```

does someone know what I configured wrongly?`

Answer (score 0):

Answer.
The problem was that i didn't hash the password.
I added the following password validation in my serialization class:

```
def validate_password(self, password):
    if len(password) < 8:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"Error":"Password has to be at least 8 characters"})
    if not any(char.isupper() for char in password):
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"Error": "Password must contain at least one capital letter"})

    if not any(char.isdigit() for char in password):
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"Error": "Password must contain at least one number"})

    if not re.search(r'[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]', password):
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"Error": "Password must contain at least one special character (!@#$%^&*(),.?\":{}|<>)"})
    return make_password(password)
```

also make sure that in your setting's "User_ID_FIELD" you change it's value from username to email.